# How does IEnumerable returns a element/Item in the method which has Yield return

Tags: c#

```
class Program {
    static List<int> MyList;
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        MyList = new List<int>() { 1,24,56,7};
        var sn = FilterWithYield();
    }

    static IEnumerable<int> FilterWithYield() {
        foreach (int i in MyList) {
            if (i > 3)
                yield return i;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Question :  IEnumerable is kind of read-only type.So my question is how does IEnumerable will return exactly one element. IEnumerable does not have something to Add method . Does it returns from the  property "Current" of IEnumerator.?? if so can we say each time when yield return is returning one element/item it's the current property of IEnumerator?

Comment: Sounds like you might want to read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter11/StreamingAndIterators.aspx and http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter6/IteratorBlockImplementation.aspx

Comment: Jon's advice is good. You might want to read this also: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20080812-00/?p=21273

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `yield` keyword, you indicate that the method is an iterator. Using `yield` to define an iterator removes the need for an explicit extra class that holds the state for an enumeration.

When you consume an iterator method by using a `foreach` statement, each iteration of the `foreach` loop calls the iterator method. When a `yield return` statement is reached in the iterator method, expression is returned, and the current location in code is retained. Execution is restarted from that location the next time that the iterator function is called.